# Rest Api Uri structure for input of type List<Dictionary >

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I want to create a REST APi for which the method looks like -

```
void TestMtd( List<Dictionary<int, float[]>> inputValues)
```

What should the RESP API url look like for this ?

```
http://MyService/Test.svc/json/TestMtd?inputValues=**???????????**
```

Answer (score 0):

RESTful services does not implement an exact way to transfer the info, you can use path, query string, form string or even multipart data, so you can do it as you want, but in your case, instead of using GET method with all the data in the query, a POST or PUT is more appropiate (and you will not hit the query string limit).

As a recommendation, use POST to send temporary data (or files) and PUT to store it permanently, it makes more sense to anyone using that API.